# How to prevent html tag in a flutter text widget

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter text widget in my login screen that users enters their username in plain text.
How can I prevent then from entering HTML characters in the field.

For example, they enter `<p>myname</p>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using RegEx for that like so

```dart
 String stripHtml(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty) {
      return s;
    }
    var regex = RegExp(r'<[^>]*>');
    return s.replaceAll(regex, '');
  }
```